# Summarize snakemake steps singly: one per rule in Snakefile

Tags: snakemake

In Snakemake, is it possible to crank out a summary file that lists, for each rule, whether any invocations of that rule have failed? I have thousands of jobs that get executed for some of my rules, and I don't want to sift through thousands of logs. I know it is possible to do similar things: for example, `--rulegraph` is like `--dag` but with one node per rule instead of one per job. So, `--dag` is to `--rulegraph` as `--summary` is to what I want.